# How to resemble hyperbolic trigonometric functions (HTF) from normal trigonometric functions(NTF)??

Tags: functions

There are many properties of HTF similliar but little different than NTF, Is there some pattern or rule that makes me, who only knows NTF, able to get HTF from direct resemblence to NTF?

Comment: This becomes transparent when looking at them in the complex plane. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways of defining sine and cosine is from the exponential function:
$$ \cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} \qquad \sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

You can also define hyperbolic trig functions like this:
$$ \cosh x = \frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}{2} \qquad \sinh x = \frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2}$$

The similarity is pretty obvious in this form. And it also makes it easy to get a relation for one in terms of the other:
$$ \cos x = \cosh ix, \ \cosh x = \cos ix, \ \sin x = -i \sinh ix, \ \sinh x = -i \sin ix $$